# How do I hide the panel for extra small devices but still show the content of the panel

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, hide, panel

I have ASP controls in a twitter-bootstrap panel. 
On extra small devices, I need to hide the panel but still show the ASP controls. If I use the hidden-xs class on my panel then the controls are also hidden. 
Is there a way to do this without creating duplicate ASP controls?

```
<div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">Milestones</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ShowMe" CssClass="form-control"/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Etcetera" CssClass="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result should be as follows for "sm", "md", & "lg" 
[image]

And for "xs"
[image]

Comment: what do you want to hide? the heading only? if you hide the entire panel the content inside it also hide

Comment: @Ratheesh I want to hide the heading and the border around the panel, but still show the ASP controls. The panel border and padding adds too much clutter to the screen on extra small devices, but looks nice on bigger screens. Should I add image mockups to the question?

Comment: Yes please.. You can use @media queries to reduce the padding..  Remove hidden-xs from `<div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">`

and add it to  `<div class="panel-heading hidden-xs">`

then change the styles of 'panel-default' and 'panel-body' to reduce the padding and removing the border

Comment: @Ratheesh Added images. 
Is a "@media" override the only solution, and how do I apply it to only a specific instance of 'panel-default' and 'panel-body' and not all panels on the same page?

Comment: add another class name to the `<div class="panel panel-default less-padding">`
now you can add media query like this 
`@media (min-width:480px)  { 
.less-padding{ /*Style here}
 }

or 

@media (min-width:767px)  { 
.less-padding{ /*Style here}
 }`

Comment: You can have the two inputs outside the panel and absolute position for them to be visually in the panel. Then on mobile screens you can hide the panel with hidden-xs, but the inputs will be stay visible. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Ratheesh Thanks, that's what I will do

Comment: @NadezhdaSerafimova the content for the panel is dynamic so this wont work

Comment: @CarlBartlett If it was useful, kindly upvote :)

Comment: @Ratheesh I don't think I have enough rep to upvote, but if you make an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove hidden-xs from `<div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">` and add it to `<div class="panel-heading hidden-xs">`

Then add another class name like '**hide-paddingAndBorder-xs**' to the panel `<div class="panel panel-default hide-paddingAndBorder-xs">` now you can add media query like this 
`@media (min-width:786px) { .hide-paddingAndBorder-xs{ /*Style here to remove padding and border*/} }`